# Is there any way to make this Python function run for more intervals?

Tags: python, function, formatting

I am extremely new to python and just wrote up this really simple code. In the end this is something I made just to get my feet wet and my head wrapped around coding. Python is my first language, I started learning it a couple days ago.

And yes, I am aware that this was a very roundabout choice for a coding method, it's also the first thing I ever produced myself that is more than a couple lines long. So, in the end, is there any way I could make the function Question run more times without running into an issue with variables being returned? I am unsure as to whether that would actually be an issue or I am just too tired to see reason right now. I know I would need to create more if statements for the results section. That much is obvious.

```
name = raw_input("Please enter you preferred name: ")
print "Welcome, %r, to the general stupidity quiz." % name
raw_input("\n\tPlease press any button to continue")

question1 = "\n\nWhat is the equivilent of 2pi in mathmatics? "
answer1 = "tao"
answer1_5 = "Tao"
question2 = "\nWhat is 2 + 2? "
answer2 = "4"
w = 0

def Question(question, answerq, answere, inputs):
    user_answer = raw_input(question)
    if user_answer in [str(answerq), str(answere)]:
        print "Correct!"
        x = inputs + 1
        return x
    else:
        print "False!"
        x = inputs
        return x

x = Question(question1, answer1, answer1_5, w)
x = Question(question2, answer2, answer2, x)

print "\nYou got " + str(x) + " questions correct..."
if x == 2:
    print "You're not stupid!"
elif x == 1:
    print "You're not smart!"
else:
    print "I hate to tell you this...but..."
raw_input()
```

I added a raw_input() at the end so my cmd window wouldn't close. I know I could use ubuntu (recently uninstalled it) and I could also just run the code using the cmd window, but it's just a thing I tagged onto the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should aim to have your functions be self contained and do one thing. Your function checks the correctness of a user input to an question and increments a counter. That is clearly two things. I will move the incrementing of the counter out of the function:

```
def question(question, answerq, answere):
    user_answer = raw_input(question)
    if user_answer in [str(answerq), str(answere)]:
        print "Correct!"
        return True
    else:
        print "False!"
        return False

x = 0
if question(question1, answer1, answer1_5):
    x += 1
if question(question2, answer2, answer2):
    x += 1
```

Now I am going to clean it up a little by changing some names to be more meaningful and not assuming that every question will always have exactly two answers:

```
def question(question, correct_answers):
    user_answer = raw_input(question)
    if user_answer in correct_answers:
        print "Correct!"
        return True
    else:
        print "False!"
        return False

correct_count = 0
if question(question1, [answer1, answer1_5]):
    correct_count += 1
if question(question2, [answer2, answer2]):
    correct_count += 1
```

To learn more, look into coding best practices and coding style. I recommend reading [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming!  It's hard to tell what you are exactly after here but it seems to me like you want to be able to ask a bunch of different questions without writing more code each time.

One thing you can do is put your list of questions/answers into a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
quiz = [("what is one + one? ", "2"), ("what is 2 + 2? ", "4")]
```

Here we are only allowing one correct answer so we need to change the `Question()` function (we can still accept "Tao" and "tao" by calling `answer.lower()` to remove capitalisation problems):

```
def Question(question, answer):
    user_answer = raw_input(question)
    if user_answer.lower() == answer:
        print "Correct!"
        x = inputs + 1
        return x
    else:
        print "False!"
        x = inputs
        return x
```

Now all we have to do is call the Question function for each question in the `quiz` list:

```
for q in quiz:
    Question(q[0], q[1])
```